# How to get around missing gzip_stream.h from protobuf packages in CentOS

Tags: protocol-buffers, centos6, yum

In trying to build some code I downloaded that relies on protobuf, I ran into a problem that the protobuf packages in CentOS don't include the file gzip_stream.h. The code I downloaded assumes that gzip_stream.h is included in the protobuf package. gzip_stream.h is included in the protobuf packages in Ubuntu, and the code I downloaded built fine. Is there a way to get around the missing gzip_stream.h in CentOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried downloading all the protobuf and zlib packages available with yum, but none of them seemed to include gzip_stream.h. I ended up having to download and build protobuf [from Google](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list), and this solved the problem. If someone knows of a better solution, please do let me know.

UPDATE: As directed by @Kenton Varda, I tried filing a bug on this. I found that this bug is already a with Fedora EPEL. It was filed about 2.5 years ago, and it appears that it hasn't been touched for about a year: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815587).

Comment: This sounds like a bug in CentOS's protobuf package -- they probably built the package without gzip support (it's a compile-time option), but they should really include it. Maybe file a bug against them?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into filing the bug.

Comment: Update: I filed a bug with CentOS. They passed the buck. This is the response I got: "This isn't a centos package. This package comes from EPEL. you would need to file your bug report with them." So that's what I plan to do.